# Move video on browser window to different location based on video time

Tags: css, html

I have two videos, a smaller one and a bigger one, and I want to change the position of the smaller video on the screen based on the time elapsed. The second, bigger video will stay immobile.

For example, I want to accomplish something along the lines of: At 0-5 seconds elapsed in the video, make the smaller video be located at the lower right corner of the big video (overlapping). At 5-10 seconds elapsed, move it to the upper right corner of the bigger video. At 10-15 seconds, move it to the center of the bigger video, etc.

Right now, the video isn't moving at all. I'm not sure how to make it move the way I want to. The code is below:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.3/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" type="text/css"/>
    <style>
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <video class="video" id="v1" width="700" height="700" autoplay>
            <source src="mov_aaa.mp4" type="video/mp4">
        </video>
    </div>
    <div id="d2">
        <video class="video" id="v2" width="400" height="400" autoplay>
            <source src="mov_bbb.mp4" type="video/mp4">         
        </video> 
    </div>

    <script>
    var myVid = document.getElementById("v2");
    var myDiv = document.getElementById("d2");

    function myFunc() {
        var timeAt = myVid.currentTime;  
        if (timeAt > 5 && timeAt <= 30) {
            myDiv.style.left = "50px";
            myDiv.style.top = "50px";
        } else if (timeAt > 30 && timeAt <= 60){
            myDiv.style.left = "150px";
            myDiv.style.top = "150px";
        } else if (timeAt > 60 && timeAt <= 90){
            myDiv.style.left = "250px";
            myDiv.style.top = "250px";
        }
    }

    myVid.addEventListener("timeupdate", myFunc);
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: did you set the position attribute for the video css as "absolute" and it's parent position as "relative"? Are the "myDiv.style.left =..." lines getting run? Can't you inspect the div left and top values on your browser?

Comment: Changing the position attributes to absolute and relative like you said solved the problem. Thanks!